# javascript proprietary date format and prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I use a proprietary date format that looks like this:

```
var TheUserDate = "3.11.2012.4.3"; // is March 11th 2012 4:03AM
```

I created this format because my application uses a lot of timezone changes and I didn't want to rely on the browser's clock for that.

I have code like this everywhere:

```
var DateArray = TheUserDate.split(".");

var TheMonth = parseInt($.trim(DateArray[0]), 10);
var TheDay = parseInt($.trim(DateArray[1]), 10);
var TheYear = parseInt($.trim(DateArray[2]), 10);
```

How can I rewrite this so that it emulated the .getMonth() .getYear() functions that are built into javascript. I'm thinking I need to modify the prototype of strings but this is my first attempt at doing something like this. I'd like to have functions like:

```
var TheMonth = TheUserDate.getMyMonth();
var TheDay = TheUserDate.getMyDay();
var TheYear = TheUserDate.getMyYear();
var TheDate = TheUserDate.getMyDate(); // to convert my format back to a javascript date.
```

How should I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ISO8601 date format YYYY-MM-DD THH:mm:ssZ and there are datetime standardisation libraries for javascript, along with the UTC methods to avoid timezone issues. The biggest issue with Date values in JavaScript is that there is a lot of undefined behaviour in the Date objects. For anyone who needs a consistent Date api I would suggest using a fixed implementation that overrides the default Date object, allowing for consistent behaviour across all browsers, but do be careful if you have other libraries which are dependent on this.

I have used https://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601/ in the past without issues

http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

[Does Javascript/EcmaScript3 support ISO8601 date parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479714/does-javascript-ecmascript3-support-iso8601-date-parsing)

## Update

As requested, to actually achieve what you want if you don't want to use a standards compliant date format, this is how you might go about implementing the object you want

```
var UserDate = (function () {

    function UserDate(dateString) {
        var dateArray= dateString.split('.'), i;

        if (dateArray.length !== 5) {
        // Handle this however you want, throw exception, 
        // bad date type etc

        }

        // No need to trim, parseInt doesn't care about 
        // leading or trailing whitespace
        for (i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i += 1) {
            dateArray[i] = parseInt(dateArray[i], 10);
        }


        // Check that the date array is well formed here if you want, 
        // check for NaN and value range
        // ...

        this._dateArray = dateArray;   
    }

    // Creates a date string from the internal date array
    UserDate.prototype.getDate = function () {
        var dateString = "", i;

        for (i = 0; i < this._dateArray.length; i += 1) {
            dateString += this._dateArray[i];
            if (i < this._dateArray.length - 1) {
                dateString += ".";
            }
        }

        return dateString;
    };

    // Returns the day value from the internal date array
    UserDate.prototype.getDay = function () {
        return this._dateArray[0];
    };

    // Returns the month from the internal date array
    UserDate.prototype.getMonth = function () {
        return this._dateArray[1];
    };

    // Returns the year from the internal data array
    UserDate.prototype.getYear = function()  {
        return this._dateArray[2];
    };

    // Returns the hour from the internal date array
    UserDate.prototype.getHour = function()  {
        return this._dateArray[3];
    };

    // Returns the minute from the internal date array
    UserDate.prototype.getMinute = function()  {
        return this._dateArray[4];
    };

    // more prototypes here


    return UserDate;

}());
```

With my tests in the console:

```
> var someDate = new UserDate("3.11.2012.4.3");
> someDate.getDate()    
  "3.11.2012.4.3"
> someDate.getYear()
  2012
> someDate.getMonth()
  11
> someDate.getDay()
  3
> someDate.getHour()
  4
> someDate.getMinut()
  3
```

Seriously don't consider editing String.prototype to give you this functionality. It's very bad practice to extend the native prototypes in JavaScript unless you are really sure what you are doing. It certainly doesn't make any sense to be adding such bespoke functionality to a general purpose string object. If you need global access to this UserDate object then make it a global object as it would be in this example. The danger is that you don't know what third party libraries are doing to the prototype.

http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/

Might be worth a read if you're interested in the arguments in general. If you really really really want to extend the string prototype then you could do something like

```
String.prototype.getDay = function () {
    return this.split('.')[0];
}
```

But this will make me a sad chicken.

Comment: no, I'm not looking to change my date format, I'm looking to enhance my date format with prototypes.

Comment: I don't know why you wouldn't adopt well established standard and use a solution that is already proven. I know it doesn't answer your question but I couldn't have people thinking a proprietary date format is the way to go about any timezone issue, however I will knock out an exact solution for your problem if someone doesn't get there before me.

Comment: The format I have makes server-side json parsing and serializing easy.

Comment: Well the idea is that if you use a standard then there will be code in most languages that you choose to parse the format that you are using. Whatever server side language you are using the likelihood of there being an ISO8601 date/time format parser (in the standard library or 3rd party) is high. However, I have written an example using one of the possible OO patterns (tends to be the most popular). If you need any further explanation then please ask.

Comment: ok, cool code. UserDate was just a name of a variable for this example. What if my string variable is called ThisOtherDate and I have ThisOtherDate = "3.3.2012.20.3"; ? Shouldn't we add a prototype to string? Will it work if I just replace UserDate with String?

Comment: You can extend the string prototype, but you really really shouldn't. Create a new object in this case. Say you have a string called ThisOtherDate. You would create a new UserDate object from it. var ThisOtherUserDate = new UserDate(ThisOtherDate); Manipulate the object however you like (you can add setters to the prototype) and then replace the original ThisOtherDate if you want by saying

ThisOtherDate = ThisOtherUserDate.getDate();

Comment: You have to remember that the string type is a global prototype and it will affect every string in your context, which is bad in general unless you are aware of the consequences.

Comment: What if I just have the .getMyMonth(), .getMyYear(), and getMyYear() functions and I know they're there and how to use them. What's the danger?

Comment: Ok, got it. Well since it's considered bad practice, I'll extend the String prototype with the assumption that other people don't do it and, I'll use a really proprietary function name so that if other people also go for this practice, it won't break my code. Thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Dates are really simple.

```
var d = Date.now()
var dateString = new Date(d).toGMTString()
```

Store dates as the UTC timestamp and call `new Date(timestamp).toGMTString()` if you ever want to visually render it.

Comment: The problem is that they have both a UTC and local variation. It created some confusion so I just put this format together and now when I see a "date", it just represent an expression of a time rather than a particular point in time.

Comment: @frenchie `new Date(d).toLocaleString()` Parsing date inputs based on locale is a different (and painful issue), rendering dates based on local is easy