# What's the name of the format that facebook sends dates in and what is the simplest way to sort that format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, iso

I merge two facebook-requests, by pushing them both into a new object. That's why I need to resort the data the format looks like this:

```
2011-06-20T19:47:12+0000
```

Comment: Looks like an ISO date - [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

## See also

- [Does Javascript/EcmaScript3 support ISO8601 date parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479714/)
- [Help parsing ISO 8601 date in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829569)