# How can I parse this date string consistently across browsers?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm using Javascript's Date object to parse a string into a milliseconds timestamp. I'm using Date.parse(), and the strings I'm parsing are of the following format: "2012-07-06 12:59:36-0600"

Date.parse performs nicely in Chrome, parsing into the correct timestamp I'd anticipate. However, every other browser returns "NaN" when I run the string through Date.parse().

I know that the Date object implementation is browser-specific, but I'd like to find a javascript solution that's capable of parsing strings of this type for any browser. Any suggestions on what else I could use in Javascript to achieve this?

Comment: Split the string in parts, and use the corresponding `Date.prototype.set*` method or the `Date` constructor to get a `Date` instance. Here's a regex to get started: `/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})([-+]\d{4})/`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert the input to valid [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
Date.parse("2012-07-06 12:59:36-0600".replace(' ', 'T'));
```

This was tested (and works) in Firefox.

Note:

> Note that while time zone specifiers are used during date string
>   parsing to properly interpret the argument, they do not affect the
>   value returned, which is always the number of milliseconds between
>   January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the point in time represented by the
>   argument.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This made it work in Firefox, but unfortunately didn't work in IE. Big surprise there, eh? :) I think I may just end up going with Date.js even though it's a bit more JS to load.

Comment: @mustang2009cobra - Take a look at this: https://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601/blob/master/iso8601.js

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802461/javascript-which-browsers-support-parsing-of-iso-8601-date-string-with-date-par

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479714/does-javascript-ecmascript3-support-iso8601-date-parsing

Comment: Thanks for the GitHub link! It seems to be exactly what I needed.

Comment: It works in IE9+ without the timezone part... ie, `Date.parse("2012-07-06T12:59:36");` works.

Comment: This approach is inconsistent across browsers. Firefox will interpret the date as local, while iOS WebView (and probably Safari too) will treat it as UTC.

Comment: IE 11 timezone parsing works if the timezone includes a ':' between the HH and MM timezone offset, e.g.: `Date.parse("2012-07-06T12:59:36-06:00")`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/)? Maybe you don't want to add another library, but it will solve your crossbrowser problem.

Comment: DateJS seems to be an old library, but it works for what I need here, so I think I'll use it. Any idea if it's still being supported? The most recent version looks like it's from 2007, but I might be wrong on that.

Comment: I don't see any development since 2008 judging from the Google Code repo. Not aware of anything newer that is comparable.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is consistent, you can parse it yourself:

```
var date = "2012-07-06 12:59:36-0600";
function parseDatetime(input) {
    var match = input.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})([-+]\d{4})/);
    match.shift(); // discard the "full match" index
    match[2]--;
    match[4] += parseInt(match[6],10);
    return new Date(match[0],match[1],match[2],match[3],match[4],match[5]);
}
```

Comment: You probably should have tested this before posting.  All the indices in the return should be incremented by 1.

Comment: And even then, I don't think it would handle timezones properly.

Comment: Oops. -fixes- I'm fairly sure timezones would be ok, if I used it in the right place (minutes instead of hours)